# How to filter elements search using JavaScript filter?

Tags: javascript, html, search-form

I have tried to make this filter work properly.

I set it to filter and only show what I am looking for, based on the card's classname (landing-pages-list). but this function doesn't work, how can it work?

i try implemented but i still don't understand bcs i'm a new of javascript programming

Here's the Code:

```
<section class="content-special-sites page-section">
            <div class="landing-pages-wrapcontent">
                <div class="list-special-sites-wrapper">
                    <div id="list-item" class="landing-pages-row">
                        <div class="landing-pages-column pria">
                            <div class="landing-pages-card">
                                <img src="assets/images/list-1.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="landing-pages-container">
                                    <div class="landing-pages-date">17 Agustus 2019</div>
                                    <div class="landing-pages-list">G-SHOCK GA 700</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="landing-pages-button-wrapper">
                                    <a class="button-detail-list" href="#lihat-detail-list1" target="_blank">Lihat
                                        Detail</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="landing-pages-column pria">
                            <div class="landing-pages-card">
                                <img src="assets/images/list-2.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="landing-pages-container">
                                    <div class="landing-pages-date">17 Agustus 2019</div>
                                    <div class="landing-pages-list">SPINNAKER VINTAGE HULL</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="landing-pages-button-wrapper">
                                    <a class="button-detail-list" href="#lihat-detail-list2" target="_blank">Lihat
                                        Detail</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="landing-pages-column pria">
                            <div class="landing-pages-card">
                                <img src="assets/images/list-3.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="landing-pages-container">
                                    <div class="landing-pages-date">17 Agustus 2019</div>
                                    <div class="landing-pages-list">SEIKO 5 SPORTS</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="landing-pages-button-wrapper">
                                    <a class="button-detail-list" href="https://first.id/special-site/seiko-5/"
                                        target="_blank">Lihat Detail</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="landing-pages-column wanita">
                            <div class="landing-pages-card">
                                <img src="assets/images/list-4.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="landing-pages-container">
                                    <div class="landing-pages-date">17 Agustus 2019</div>
                                    <div class="landing-pages-list">ALEXANDRE CHRISTIE</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="landing-pages-button-wrapper">
                                    <a class="button-detail-list"
                                        href="https://first.id/special-site/alexandre-christie/" target="_blank">Lihat
                                        Detail</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="landing-pages-column pria">
                            <div class="landing-pages-card">
                                <img src="assets/images/list-5.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="landing-pages-container">
                                    <div class="landing-pages-date">17 Agustus 2019</div>
                                    <div class="landing-pages-list">SPINNAKER VINTAGE CROFT</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="landing-pages-button-wrapper">
                                    <a class="button-detail-list"
                                        href="https://first.id/special-site/spinnaker-vintage-croft/"
                                        target="_blank">Lihat Detail</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="landing-pages-column wanita">
                            <div class="landing-pages-card">
                                <img src="assets/images/list-6.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="landing-pages-container">
                                    <div class="landing-pages-date">17 Agustus 2019</div>
                                    <div class="landing-pages-list">SPINNAKER PRO HELIUM</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="landing-pages-button-wrapper">
                                    <a class="button-detail-list"
                                        href="https://first.id/special-site/spinnaker-pro-helium/" target="_blank">Lihat
                                        Detail</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="landing-pages-column pria">
                            <div class="landing-pages-card">
                                <img src="assets/images/list-7.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="landing-pages-container">
                                    <div class="landing-pages-date">17 Agustus 2019</div>
                                    <div class="landing-pages-list">TOMMY HILFIGER</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="landing-pages-button-wrapper">
                                    <a class="button-detail-list" href="#list-7" target="_blank">Lihat
                                        Detail</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="landing-pages-load-more">
                        <center><a class="landing-pages-load-more-ajax" id="load-more">Load More</a>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

and this is a javascript

```
function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, card, list, a, i;
        input = document.getElementById("searchbar");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        card = document.getElementById("list-item");
        list = card.getElementsByTagName("div .landing-pages-list");
        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            a = list[i].getElementsByTagName("div .landing-pages-list")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                list[i].parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "";
            } else {
                list[i].parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

when i type, not work

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByTagName has a tag name followed the CSS class which will not find anything.

If you were able to use this method it would be getElementsByTagName(“div”);

However since the above would get all divs on the page you should use getElementsByClassName(“landing-pages-list”) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The "card" variable should be the tag that contains all the list-items

- Assigned an id **"main-card"** to it

> class="content-special-sites page-section" **id="main-container"**

- And then all the sub-cards which we will be determining their visibility should have a common class. So you add "sub-card" to their classes

> class = "landing-pages-column pria **sub-card**"

-Finally, we specify the class of the tags in which we want to compare out search value. in this case its **landing-pages-list**

> a = list[i].getElementsByClassName("landing-pages-list")[0];

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, card, list, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("searchbar");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    card = document.getElementById("main-container");
    list = card.getElementsByClassName("sub-card");
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        a = list[i].getElementsByClassName("landing-pages-list")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            list[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            list[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

[View and Run code](https://jsfiddle.net/shugar/1fv4buo2/2/)